# ReactJS styled-components & CSS on background-image not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create the landing page for a project of mine and I ran into several problems that I just can't seem to fix. I'm using ReactJS with styled components for styling.

[This is the full picture of the hero image on a desktop size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBbyv.png)

[This is for the mobile version of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F1xd.png)

Above are pictures of the hero images both for desktop size and mobile size. Below are what I have so far. You will be able to see the problems along with the code I have.

[what I have with the desktop hero image so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K08lW.png)

[how it looks at tablet size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86tyC.png)

(Please ignore the text along with the button on the background image for now)

As you can see the background images look different from the full picture. Either they're getting cut off or the full image is not showing.

[picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqVr7.png)

I will also write the code (ReactJS first):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-scroll'
import subittHero from '../../images/subittHeroImg.svg'
import subittHeroMobile from '../../images/subittHeroImgMobile.svg'
import { Button } from '../ButtonElements'
import { HeroContainer, HeroBg, ImgBg,
    HeroContent, HeroH1, HeroSub, HeroSubPink,
     HeroBtnWrapper, ArrowForward, ArrowRight} from './HeroElements'

const HeroSection = () => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)

  const onHover = () => {
      setHover(!hover)
  }

  return (
    <HeroContainer>
        <HeroBg>
            {/* <img src={subittHero} width="100%"/> */}
            <ImgBg image={subittHero} mobile={subittHeroMobile} />
        </HeroBg>
        <HeroContent>
            <HeroH1>Welcome</HeroH1>
            <HeroSub>SUBSCRIBE HOW <HeroSubPink> YOU </HeroSubPink> WANT TO</HeroSub>
            <HeroBtnWrapper>
                <Button 
                to="signup" 
                onMouseEnter={onHover} 
                onMouseLeave={onHover}
                primary="true"
                dark="true">
                    
                    Explore {hover ? <ArrowForward /> : <ArrowRight/>}
                </Button>
            </HeroBtnWrapper>
        </HeroContent>
    </HeroContainer>
  )
}

export default HeroSection
```

The styled-component code just for the three tags in relations to the image:

```
export const HeroContainer = styled.div`
 background: #231F20;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 0;
`

export const HeroBg = styled.div`
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 grid-column: 1 / 3;
 grid-row: 1 / 2;
 align-self: stretch;
`
    
export const ImgBg = styled.div`
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 background: #F2F2F2;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url(${(props) => props.image});

 @media (max-width: 768px) {
    background-image: url(${(props) => props.mobile});
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
`
```

I've tried experimenting with background-size: cover attribute, position, width, height, etc. but nothing seems to get it to work.

It only works when I do an html img tag (commented out on line 20) with a width of 100%.

I'm trying to code it so that the page will be fully responsive on different desktop resolutions and mobile device sizes.

Comment: You're attempting to apply the object-fit property to a background image, it seems. 

object-fit applies to replaced elements (think <img/> or <video/>). For a background image, the property you want to set is background-size. For your particular use case, probably background-size: cover.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bg-image {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 512px;
  height: 25vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/1920x960/000000/fff')"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of applying object-fit (since this property applies to replaced elements rather than backgrounds — see my note above), you can affect your background image the way you want to with the background-size and background-position properties.

`background-size: cover`, for example, will ensure that your image always fills  its parent frame. Throw `background-position: center` on it to make sure that the image center remains in the frame's center.

Of course, there are other size and positioning options as well. But this seems to be more or less what you're after.

[MDN - background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

[MDN - background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

[Smashing Magazine - A Deep Dive Into object-fit And background-size In CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/10/object-fit-background-size-css/)